# Is sharepoint the right tool to use?

Tags: xml, database, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have been asked to create a system that works on top of sharepoint 2013, but the more I read about sharepoint I am dubious if it is the right tool for the job. Forgetting that I need users, roles (capabilities), teams(groups) and notifications for a second, I have the following core functionality:

Create a system that listens/talks to two separate feeds, both communicated in XML format, Feed A gets data from a customers accounting package about latest orders, Feed B is an interface to the in-house management system.  The system I have to create sits in between those two and stores complex data from feed A (which it can show in a link and details page), and create a sub-set of data which it sends to Feed B.

Feed B will reply with the Yes/No to the success of this data input, as well as having status changes to the order, such as "in progress", "shipping" or "delivered".

The system will poll Feed A and B on regular intervals for updates, which it will apply to it's set of data.

There is a bunch of other requirements, but this core set is vital and what I will be focused on first.

Anyhow, in my mind I keep on thinking that Sharepoint is more of a document management system than a database interface via the web.  Am I getting this all wrong??  is Sharepoint the right choice??

Comment: I do not see in your core requirements any need in record managment system at all. Maybe you should create simple middle application (windows service for example)?

Comment: Thanks Yevgeniy, I have come to the same conclusion.  It's just overkill at present.  So as ever, I am going to simplify :)

Comment: It sounds to me that you're describing a Service Bus. You might want to check this out, http://particular.net/NServiceBus.